# What is the maximum number of elements in $S$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, contest-math, divisibility

Let $S$ be a subset of $\{1,2,3,...,50\}$ such that no pair of distinct elements in $S$ has a sum divisible by $7$. What is the maximum number of elements in $S$?

Comment: It should be $$8\{\equiv1\}+7\{\equiv2\text{ or }5\}+7+1\{\equiv0\}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't have two numbers whose sum is divisible by 7, you can't have a number that $\equiv 1$ (mod 7) and another that $\equiv = 6$ (mod 7), and similarly you can't have one being $\equiv 2$ and a second $\equiv 5$, or the first $\equiv 3$ and the second $\equiv 4$.  Finally, you can't have two numbers that are both $\equiv 0$.

Now, there are 8 numbers that are $\equiv 1$, and 7 for all the other groups, so definitely pick all $\equiv 1$: 1,8,15,22,29,36,43,50

So that's 8 numbers

Then you can pick all $\equiv 2$: 2,9,16,23,30,37,44 *or* pick all $\equiv 5$

So that's another 7

Then you can pick all $\equiv 3$: 3,10,17,24,31,38,45 *or* pick all $\equiv 4$

Which is another 7

And finally, you pick 1 more number that $\equiv 0$ such as 7.

Total: 8+7+7+1 = 23

Comment: I agree. I think it is also worth noting that there are as many numbers with remainder 2 (or 2 mod 7) as with remainder 5 (same with 3 and 4) so it doesn't matter which class you choose. While with 1 and 6, numbers with remainder 1 are more in that set, so we choose them.

Comment: @B.A Yeah, I should add that, thanks!